# a naive question about homogeneous polynomials

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Suppose $p$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $n$ complex variables. Let S be the hypersurface
defined by $p(z)=0$. Then is the 1-form $dp/p$ always non-exact on the complement $C^n\setminus S$?

Any answer or reference is appreciated.

Ron Yang

Comment: Trivial objection: p(z) = 1 is a homogeneous polynomial. 

Answer (score 6):

Assume that $p$ is non-zero.  If the form $dp/p$ were exact, then locally a primitive would be $log(p)+const$; this is easily seen not to work as soon as you can "loop around" $S$ (e.g. restrict everything to a line intersecting $S$ and see what happens there).  Thus the form $dp/p$ is exact if and only if $S$ is empty, and hence if and only if $p$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess the same thing can be said for all nontrivial polynomials.

Comment: Yes, the fact that $p$ is homogeneous plays no role in this argument.